# How access my Service (DependencyInjection) inside my Type classes?

Tags: forms, service, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a Service (DependencyInjection) that i create, and i use that on my controllers as:

```
$this->get("service_name")->someMethod()
```

I want to know how to use that on my Form classes.

Here my example form of class:

```
namespace Company\SampleBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class AnswerType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
        // I want use: $this->get("service") here, how can i use that?
        $builder->add('answer', 'textarea');
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'answer';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Company\SampleBundle\Entity\Answer',
        );
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `$options` to achieve this. This implies you modify the `getDefaultOptions` accordingly.

```
 public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
    return array(
        'service'    => null,
        'data_class' => 'Company\SampleBundle\Entity\Answer',
    );
}
```

In your controller, when you call `createForm()`
use the `$options` argument, like this:

```
$this->createForm('Answer', null, array('service' => $service))
```

Comment: @HappyDeveloper : Are you happy now ? ;-)

Comment: Thanks. And how could we do from a nested form type ? ->add('items', 'collection', array('type' => new itemType('Item', null, array('service' => $service)),...

Comment: No, it doesn't :( In the itemType, 'service' is a key of the Options array, which is what is expected. But it's null. And I also tried with a simple value: array('service' => "testValue")

Comment: Oh right, that's normal. Use `array('type' => new itemType(), 'options' => compact('service')`, something like that...

Comment: The option "service" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "cascade_validation", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_provider", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "inherit_data", "intention", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "max_length", "method", "pattern"... This expection is throwed