# Advantage of creating a form as a service (rather than just a classType)?

Tags: forms, symfony, service

I have read here and there, that you could create a form as a service.But I do not really see the point of doing so.

Could anyone give me a quick example of the advantage of doing so rather than just having a form define as a class.

**No code (or not much) but just a quick concrete exemple of what I would do with form as a service that I couldn't do if it was a simple class.**

---

Here the advantage (or not) that I listed so far:

**dependancy injection** (no need to be declare as a service in fact):
   Form as a service would allow you to inject other services into it and get them thought constructor. ==> but actually no need to declare a form as a service to do so: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013603/how-access-my-service-dependencyinjection-inside-my-type-classes?rq=1) an exemple of a formType (not define as a service) using an external service.

Comment: Hi, If you reuse your form in multiple context and view is usefull. For exemple i did for create an helping form witch is aviable on all pages i store inside user prev & actual page

Comment: what the advantage? a form as a class is also reusable anywhere...

Comment: I build my form with services who is called by request in order to have information (previous & actual page)

Comment: I think your question is "should I declare form as service". My answer is : "No, if you didn't need it"

Comment: OK then my question is, can you give me an exemple of when I need to create a form as a service.

Comment: I've given you my exemple. My form contain request information so i need declare it as a service to fill it. For other case you should read the doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Comment: ok I see. Form design as a service allow you to fill the form with request information.. which is not possible if the form was define just as a class. (what kind of request is it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use case 1:

**Case**: you use your form in several places, your form requires some other services

**solution**: By declaring it as a service, you dont need to remember the class name each time, and you dont have to access the container to pass the services to the your form instance, so instead of:

```
$this->createForm('Answer', null, array('service' => $service))
```

you do `$this->createForm('Answer', 'my_form')`

and you get properly configured form. When you change the form, you dont have to change it everywhere in your code later. Its also easier to test and its harder to forget something when you dont have to pass everything to the constructor each time.

2. Use case 2

**Case**: You embed your form into other forms

**Solution**: You dont have access to the Dep.Container in your form(and you shouldnt have) so its impossible to do

```
$builder->add('Answer', new MyForm($service1,$service2))
```

inside forms, instead you do

```
 $builder->add('Answer', 'my_form')
```

3. Use case 3

**Case**: Others use your code, you form might change in different cases

**Solution**: If you declare your form as a service, you can set its class to be a parameter, so in case somebody else wants to extend you form, he can do it just by using parameters.yml, without messing with your code. Some examples might be bundles like FOSUserBundle, when you can replace the User class of different forms just by using configuration.

Comment: Just have one more question about case 2, my_form (tagType that I defined it as a service with alias myform) is embeded in an other form. but my_form is a collection also can you please let me know what should I write instead of **$builder->add('tags', 'collection', array('type'=> new tagType()))**