# Concrete examples of using a controller as a service?

Tags: php, symfony, service, controller

I read in the documentation **how to use a controller as a service**. But I am not sure what would be the purpose of it. Why not then simply use a service (a class define as a service)?

If anyone could give me some good examples of transforming a **controller** in a service that would be great.

Comment: *Why not then simply use a service* Is it possible without a controller? Controller is meant to catch requests and interact with it, I don't know if it's possible without a Controller. You should edit your question, it's unclear if you want a theoretical answer or a concrete example.

Comment: This approach is used when you are developing an `api` app

Comment: I read this question in two different ways: either you are interested in creating a **web service**, or you are asking how to move your logic from your controller class to a **service layer**. Or, perhaps these are Symfony-specific terminologies that need further expansion. Would you clarify?

Comment: so far I am not interested in creating a web service. I just read this subject in the documentation and this was not very clear to me what the purpose of defining a controller as a service. the documentation is more about how to do it rather that why you should do it or in which case this is a good way to do. (that 's all, so far... thks)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advantage of creating a form as a service (rather than just a classType)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819416/advantage-of-creating-a-form-as-a-service-rather-than-just-a-classtype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical Symfony controller uses a [Service Locater](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator) pattern to pull in it's dependencies:

```
class PersonController
{
  public function showAction()
  {
    $personRepository = 
      $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Entity\Person');
    $person = $personRepository->find(1);
    return new JsonResponse($person);
```

Getting the person repository requires the action to have quite a bit of knowledge about how to locate things. Somewhat magical in fact .  The controller is tied directly to doctrine and the framework infrastructure.

It also makes the action hard to test.  You have to make a container then define the necessary services before running the action.

Contrast that with a controller defined as a service with it's dependencies injected:

```
class PersonController
{
  protected $personRepository;
  public function __construct($personRepository) 
  {
    $this->personRepository = $personRepository;
  }
  public function showAction()
  {
    $person = $this->personRepository->find(1);
```

The action no longer needs know about how to locate the repository.  It's just there.  For testing, just need to make a repository and inject it.  Clean and simple.

Comment: and how does symfony know that it has to look in the PersonRepository? is it indicated in the configuration of the controller define as a service?

Comment: Yep.  You setup the injection in services.yml when you define the controller service.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container.  It's a powerful concept once it is understood.